# How does SCII select an opponent when playing multipalyer?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've just gotten out of the Practice League so maybe there is an option later on to select opponents.. But I was wondering, how does SCII select an opponent? I imagine its pretty region-specific as it would take latency into account - as I could swear based on some of the questions I see on here it harder in my region (Asia-Pacific)...

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/starcraft-2-matchmaking-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Starcraft II match making system picks players from your region that have similar skill.  It maintains a hidden skill number which it uses to match you against other players, and adjusts this number based on the skill number of the opponents you win and lose to.  It also does it best to make sure you have a 50% win-loss ratio.

Comment: I see so it is region based therefore a bronze player in region a could be a silver player in region b..

Comment: @Mrk Mnl not really, players can only play in one region.

Comment: Hypothetically - if they were able to. Actually non-US players can opt to have a profile in US too - havent tried yet though..